# Seemingly Inconsistent Particle Usage with the Verb 手伝う

Tags: grammar, particles, phrase-requests

When it is not specified what the helper did...

> 私はとても忙しいので、彼**を**手伝うことができない。

When both action and person being helped are specified...

> 彼女は私**に**仕事**を**手伝うように頼んだ。

When it is not specified whom the helper helped...

> 彼はこの計画**を**手伝うだろう。

Is there some patterns or It's just that I don't understand?
And if I want to say...
"Can you help me clean the classroom?" with くれる, 手伝う, and 掃除, what will the sentence be like?

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of 手伝う is:
《五他》他人の仕事をたすけて、うまく行くように力を添える。
"To help with people's work, pay effort to make sure it works out well."

So you can understand it this way:

*私はとても忙しいので、**彼を手伝う**ことができない。*

*As I am really busy, i cannot help **him ( with his work ).***

*彼女は私に**仕事を手伝う**ように頼んだ。*

*She asked me to **help with her work**.*

*彼はこの**計画を手伝う**だろう。*

*He will probably **help with the project**.*

As Japanese is a Topic-Prominent Language, the informations that are irrelevant or commonly known by both the speaker / reader are usually omitted.

So to say "Can you help me clean the classroom?" with くれる, 手伝う, and 掃除, there will be two ways:

1. 私を手伝って(、一緒に教室の掃除をして)くれませんか？
2. (私一人では大変だから、)教室の掃除を手伝ってくれませんか？

Which those information within the bracket can be optionally omitted, if you feel like it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: >As Japanese is a Topic-Prominent Language, the informations that are irrelevant or commonly known by both the speaker / reader are usually omitted. A nice explanation!